# En/Decode struct containing many interfaces with different implementations each with gob

Tags: go, gob, go-interface

I have a quite complex struct that contains many interfaces with each different implementations. For en/decoding that struct in gob I seem to have to register every implementation that could be possibly used for every interface. So I end up with a method along these lines:

```
func registerImplementations() {
    gob.Register(&Type1{})
    gob.Register(&Type2{})
    gob.Register(&Type3{})
    gob.Register(&Type4{})
    ....

}
```

which I need to call before en/decoding. Is there an easier way to do this? Or should I look into possibilities for generating this method, since it's quite tedious to keep track of all possible implementations?

Comment: If possible, I would go the route of generating the function.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) says:

```
We must register the concrete type for the encoder and decoder (which would
normally be on a separate machine from the encoder). On each end, this tells the
engine which concrete type is being sent that implements the interface.
```

So, at some point, you're going to want to call `gob.Register`, but you do want your code to be maintainable. This leaves (broadly) two options:

- Creating a function like you're doing now, calling each struct after one another.

  - Advantage: all your `Register`-calls in a list, so you'll easily spot if you miss one, and you surely won't register one twice.
  - Disadvantage: you'll have to update it when using another implementation. You'll also have to call this function some time before encoding/decoding.
- Creating something like this:

  ```
  func Register(i interface{}) error {
      gob.Register(i)
      return nil
  }
  ```

  And then when writing a new implementation in your (let's say) `dummy` package, you can put this line below / above the interface declaration.

  ```
  var regResult = reg.Register(myNewInterface{})
  ```

This will be called on startup (because it's global).

- Advantage: not having to update the `registerImplementations` method.
- Disadvantage: you'll have your registers all across your code (which can consist of a lot of files) - so you might miss one.

---

As to which is better: I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Or, instead of inventing a `nil` error return (`gob.Register` has no return value) so you can cause initialization via a global variable assignment, it would likely be cleaner/simpler to just use [`init` function(s)](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) in the package/file that defines the type.